# LDAP TLS vs. SSL

Tags: ssl, ldap

I implement LDAP authentication. I need to support both TLS & SSL.

I use the following code :

```
 Properties bindEnv = new Properties();
 LdapContext  bindCtx = null;

 ....
 if (SSL){
    bindEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://ldap.example.com:636");
 }
 else{ 
   if(TLS){
       bindEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldap.example.com:389");
   }
 }

 bindEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "INITIAL DN");    
 bindEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "PASSWORD");
 bindCtx = new InitialLdapContext(bindEnv, null);

 if(TLS){
     StartTlsResponse tls = 
         (StartTlsResponse) bindCtx.extendedOperation(new StartTlsRequest());
     tls.negotiate();
 }    

 ... Get username/password and authenticate user...
```

Now, in SSL mode , the initial DN & password are sent on SSL. In case of a problem, the initial context will throw an exception immediately.

But in TLS mode, the password is sent in a plain 389 port. The TLS starts only afterwards. 
So, what does the TLS mean? It is not secure.

It seems that in case of TLS, the right way is to open the initial context without the DN/password, start the TLS, and then use bind/reconnect?

Something like:

```
if (SSL){
     bindEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://ldap.example.com:636");
     bindEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "INITIAL DN");    
     bindEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "PASSWORD");
     bindCtx = new InitialLdapContext(bindEnv, null);
 }     
 else{ 
   if(TLS){
       bindEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldap.example.com:389");
       bindCtx = new InitialLdapContext(bindEnv, null);
       StartTlsResponse tls = 
             (StartTlsResponse) bindCtx.extendedOperation(new StartTlsRequest());
       tls.negotiate();
       bindCtx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "INITIAL DN");
       bindCtx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"PASSWORD");
       bindCtx.reconnect(null);
   }
 }
```

Is this the way to make sure the initial password is always sent securely ?

Thanks

Comment: First ask yourself, why you use different ports for SSL and TLS and what you mean by different "SSL" and "TLS", because SSL and TLS are the same thing (different versions of the same protocol). So it's not clear, what you are doing and why.

Comment: I work with different LDAP servers. If I use only SSL it means that I force all customers' LDAP servers to listen on a secured port (e.g. 636), while in TLS they can use the 389 port as well.

Comment: Well, you need to read a bit about SSL/TLS and then refine your questions (if they persist). So far it looks like you are talking about implicit and explicit modes, in which case the described behavior is perfectly correct.

Comment: Your are confusing TLS, which is a later version of the SSL protocol, with *STARTTLS,* which is an option in the LDAP and other protocols to upgrade a plaintext connection to TLS. What you are looking for is STARTTLS.

Answer (score 0):

Just like LDAP over SSL, LDAP over TLS should be listening on port 636 not 389.  TLS should be synonymous with SSL in this context (e.g. TLS is simply the next version of SSL.., SSL1->SSL3->TLS1->TLS11->TLS12)